# Error while trying to load the gem 'devise. ActiveSupport: Duration can't be coerced into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activesupport

I've been trying to fix this error for a while now without finding any helpful, help please.

I'm trying to run migrations on my ROR app using the devise gem. But I get an error from ActiveSupport 'Duration can't be coerced into Integer'. this happened then I try to run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I'm not sure if it has something to do with the code on the migrations or if it is something about a new devise version.
This is the error message:

```
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb:155: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'devise'.
Gem Load Error is: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Integer
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:50:in `*'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:50:in `days'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:55:in `weeks'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise.rb:121:in `<module:Devise>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
TypeError: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Integer
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm using:

```
ruby '2.4.0'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2.0'
```

Please let me know how can I make this a better question.
greetings.

Edit:
This is one of the migrations files:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at
  t.datetime :remember_created_at
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip
  t.timestamps
end
end
end
```

Also, when trying 
    bundle exec rake db:migrate
I get almost the same:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:285: warning: circular argument reference - now
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.5/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb:155: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'devise'.
Gem Load Error is: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Integer
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:50:in `*'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:50:in `days'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb:55:in `weeks'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise.rb:121:in `<module:Devise>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/lib/devise.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
TypeError: ActiveSupport::Duration can't be coerced into Integer
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/sam/aplicaciones/pess/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/home/sam/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Are you running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` or just `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: can you post the migration file?

Comment: @virtuexru I'm just runing rake db:migrate, but I get the same output when trying bundle exec rake db:migrate.

Comment: @RockwellRice, sure, I'll edit the post ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I faced this yesterday while getting rails 3.2 and ruby 2.4 working together. I fixed it by monkey patching the activesupport library which is where the problem lies.

solution: switch the order of multiplication, put Duration first

Include the following code in your rails initializers:

```
# pulled from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.22.5/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/time.rb

class Numeric
  def days
    ActiveSupport::Duration.new(24.hours * self, [[:days, self]])
  end
  alias :day :days

  def weeks
    ActiveSupport::Duration.new(7.days * self, [[:days, self * 7]])
  end
  alias :week :weeks

  def fortnights
    ActiveSupport::Duration.new(2.weeks * self, [[:days, self * 14]])
  end
  alias :fortnight :fortnights
end

# pulled from https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.22.5/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/time.rb

class Integer
  def months
    ActiveSupport::Duration.new(30.days * self, [[:months, self]])
  end
  alias :month :months

  def years
    ActiveSupport::Duration.new(365.25.days * self, [[:years, self]])
  end
  alias :year :years
end
```

Comment: With this answer and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44286212), you are my hero of the day.

Comment: Same as @JetBlue

Comment: I'm sorry - what exactly should I do with this one? I created a new file in `config/initializers` and put it there, but it didn't work

Comment: Where do I need to put the Integer and Duration classes? @Thomas Dziedzic

Comment: Hey @mychemicalro, I fixed it like this: https://www.udemy.com/learn-ruby-on-rails-from-scratch/learn/v4/questions/5836226

Comment: i fixed this by adding this code to environment.rb file not initialesers file

Comment: @AlexBuznik it appears that the Udemy link requires you to purchase the course ($25) to get access to the question. Please can you share the details of your solution?

Comment: Sure, my bad. Not much more other than Thomas' advice  - forked activesupport and fixed the issue there per this answer (https://github.com/beshur/activesupport not updated since then) , but also switched to heroku stack 16 (which may already be phasing out, I guess). Not  sure why I put the link to udemy for this.

Answer (score 22):

Faced the issue today while trying to upgrade old app to rails 4.

The issue is ruby version(2.4.0) and not devise itself. Consider to use ruby-2.3.3 or lower and it's going to work like a charm!

Comment: Yea, that's what I did. Rails 3.2 is not supported on ruby 2.4, so had to use lower version.

Comment: It works for me! Thank You. I have to upgrade my Rails 4 to Rails 5. But, I've used ruby-2.3.3.

Comment: For future users, consider using ruby-2.3.4 or higher to avoid huge vulns present in 2.3.3 and prior versions

Comment: This kind of wonky dependency management seems particularly pronounced in the Ruby ecosystem...

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had the same problem trying to install and run `activeadmin` under these conditions:

rails 3.2.22.5
ruby 2.3.8

The [solution by Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44286374/753451) did not fully work for me, because the ActiveSupport was called before the application could start.

Solution that worked for me:
I extracted the ActiveSupport as a separate gem, [forked it](https://github.com/beshur/activesupport), applied the above patch by Thomas and did some additional fixes so it could be run as a gem, outside of rails.
I also added this gem before `activeadmin`, so when `Duration` was required it run my patched version:

```
# Gemfile extract
gem 'activesupport', :git => 'git://github.com/beshur/activesupport.git'
gem 'activeadmin', '0.6.6'
```

Then I switched my heroku app to use stack heroku-16 ([more on stacks here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack)), however it still requires ruby 2.3.8.

Hope it helps someone later, though it's already outdated versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and let me know the output. Without `bundle exec` in front it won't know which gems to use & will use native (system) gems.

Also try running `bundle update` and then re-running the migration.

Comment: Thanks for answering Virtuexru, I tried bundle update and after that bundle exec rake db:migrate but the output is almost the same. I edited the post.

Comment: Can you remove the version for `devise` in the gemfile? Meaning have it be: gem 'devise' and run `bundle` first before running` bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: Also do you have `nodejs` installed? You might need it.

Comment: virtuexru, I did exactly what you said, but it doesn't change the out put.

Comment: Hmmm; l would imagine its something wrong with the `devise` gem.. I can't find anything else on the web related to this error. Sorry :( Worst case scenario you can open up an issue here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues

Comment: Got any solutions for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Bot just found a solution, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when migrating a legacy app. Once you upgrade Rails to 4.2 you can upgrade the Ruby version to 2.4 and then continue along your upgrade path with both Rails and Ruby.

I recommend using the bootboot gem in your Gemfile so you can test running specs in older and newer Rails versions with just an environment variable, without having to switch Git branches.

Answer (score -1):

Today, I faced with same problem, but different versions, my ruby version 2.4.2 and rails version 4.0.13.

I was getting the same error, and fixed it now. Thanks to @thomas-dziedzic.

The solution is:

1. I pulled from
   https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/32f215c3014e580e512db5e8772d0deadf3d6497
2. I edited according to this link then edit https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/32f215c3014e580e512db5e8772d0deadf3d6497/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb

When I editing active_support, the problem fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

Switch to rails version at least 5.0.2, remove your Gemfile.lock and run `bundle update`.

`5.2.0` is the most recent, this was released April 9, '18..

Comment: Why 5.0.2? `1.day` works fine for me on Ruby 2.4.2 and Rails 4.2.10. The original poster experienced the bug on Rails 4.1.1. So the problem was fixed sometime between those versions.

Comment: Security, and to help oneself in the future when versions become even more difficult to update. If the OP is referencing gems that are outdated, and monkey patching system libraries it is likely to come back some day needing more work than it is to bump the version as they are made available.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is 5.0.2 sufficiently secure but 5.0.1 not? It seems that if the issue is specific to a version of Rails, it would be more useful to say what version the issue was fixed in rather than to say what version the issue was fixed in that also is secure enough by some unspecified standard.

Comment: It is generally a better approach to use the latest stable in any project. Doing so gives you better odds at having fewer security holes in your application. This is because newer versions have patches or account for any vulnerabilities discovered throughout the life of the software package. So the proper approach does not involve modifying system libraries and creating more holes, it is to update your system for the long run and capture these additionl benefits. I am not sure of the sepcifics of your question regarding bug fixes in rails 5.01 vs 5.0.2, maybe better to ask a new question.