# Mismatched ruby version after downgrade from 2.4.1 to 2.3.3 while running bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While attempting to solve another issue identified in this thread:
 [Error while trying to load the gem 'devise. ActiveSupport: Duration can't be coerced into Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703128/error-while-trying-to-load-the-gem-devise-activesupport-duration-cant-be-coe), I followed the suggested solution and changed my ruby version from 2.4.1 to 2.3.3 using rbenv. I also made similar changes in my Gemfile to reflect the new ruby version. However, when I tried to bundle install again, it throws an error saying that my ruby version is 2.4.1, when my Gem specified 2.3.3. However, running `ruby -v` shows my ruby version is on 2.3.3.

```
$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.4.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.3
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

Any help here would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the result of `which bundle`? Are you perhaps running the *system* bundle, not the rbenv `bundle`? In which case, you may need to `gem install bundler`.

Comment: Also, I would suggest that you use [ruby version 2.3.4](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/03/30/ruby-2-3-4-released/), not 2.3.3.

Comment: Thank you, it was due to the version of bundler I was using that was the issue. Re-installying gem install bundler did fix the issue. In regards to the ruby version, I used 2.3.3 only because it was the suggested ruby version from the solution to my previous issue.

Comment: The post you linked to was written before ruby 2.3.4 was released! You should *always* aim to use the latest patch release of a minor version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem installation is specific to ruby version, so the `bundler` you're using is likely installed to your old ruby. Try installing `bundler` again:

```
gem install bundler
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Turns out my bundler was installed to my old ruby, reinstallying bundler again did fix the problem.